# View based NSTableView: Empty/white labels on dragging

Tags: cocoa, drag-and-drop, nstableview, appkit

I setup a trivial view based NSTableView, the view is a simple NSTextField used as a label:

```swift
  func tableView(_ tv: NSTableView, viewFor tc: NSTableColumn?, row: Int)
       -> NSView?
  {
    let v = (tv.makeView(withIdentifier: viewID, owner: nil) as? NSTextField)
        ?? NSTextField()
    v.isSelectable = false
    v.isEditable   = false
    v.stringValue  = data[row] // [String]
    v.identifier   = viewID
    return v
  }
```

and then I enable *dragging* of the items using this delegate method:

```swift
  func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, pasteboardWriterForRow row: Int)
       -> NSPasteboardWriting?
  {
    return MyPasteboardItem(value: data[row])
  }
```

This works, but when I drag the row, I get an empty representation of the textfield:

[image: Empty NSTextField on drag]

(in a different setup things like image views and buttons get drawn, but the NSTextField also ends up white).

I highly suspect this is due to the NSTextField being backed by a TextLayer which doesn't get drawn if the tableview captures an image of the view hierarchy being dragged.

What is a good way to fix this? I considered implementing `draw()`, but well.

Update: If I do an own NSTextField subclass and override `draw()`, it indeed starts to work:

```
final class MyTextField : NSTextField {
  override func draw(_ dirtyRect: NSRect) {
    super.draw(dirtyRect)
  }
}
```

Looking at the thing in the view debugger shows that the Layer switches from `NSTextLayer` to `_NSViewBackingLayer` when `draw` is overridden.
But I assume this is not exactly desirable? Is there a better way to accomplish this?

Complete sample: https://gist.github.com/helje5/48728983951ab3362af43b967c554475

Answer (score 1):

Setting drawsBackground=false on the textfield fixed it for me.

If you are using xib file then untick "Draws Background" on the Text Field or in your viewFor: method something like:

```
v.drawsBackground = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with this in an NSTextField subclass, not sure whether it is a good idea:

```swift
  override public func draw(_ dirtyRect: NSRect) {
    // This switches from the UXLabel being backed by `NSTextLayer` to
    // `_NSViewBackingLayer`, which may not be desirable.
    // BUT: This enables proper drawing of the Drag&Drop cell.
    super.draw(dirtyRect)
  }
```